# How I can disable xfce mouseover popups?

Tags: popup, mouseover, xfce

I am using xfce desktop ( Fedora ), and sometimes pops up some message like mose over help.

See attached file, inside red circle.

How can I disable this message?

[image]

I have already disabled notifications ( setting -> notifications ),

But it still shows up.